# Repeated measures anova: lm vs lmer

Tags: anova, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, lm

I'm trying to reproduce several interaction test between with both `lm` and `lmer` on repeated measures (2x2x2). The reason I want to compare both methods is because SPSS's GLM for repeated measures yields the exact same results as the `lm` approach presented here, so at the end I want to compare SPSS vs R-lmer. So far, I've only managed to reproduce (closely) some of these interactions.

You'll find below a script to better illustrate my point:

```r
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
library(lmerTest)
library(MASS)

set.seed(1)

N     <- 100 # number of subjects
sigma <- 1   # popuplation sd
rho   <- .6  # correlation between variables

# X1:   a  a  a  a  b  b  b  b
# X2:   a  a  b  b  a  a  b  b
# X3:   a  b  a  b  a  b  a  b
mu <- c(5, 3, 3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 3) # means

# Simulate the data
sigma.mat <- rep(sigma, length(mu))
S <- matrix(sigma.mat, ncol = length(sigma.mat), nrow = length(sigma.mat))
Sigma <- t(S) * S * rho  
diag(Sigma) <- sigma**2
X <- data.table( mvrnorm(N, mu, Sigma) )
setnames(X, names(X), c("aaa", "aab", "aba", "abb", "baa", "bab", "bba", "bbb"))
X[, id := 1:.N]

# Long format
XL <- data.table( gather(X, key, Y, aaa:bbb) )
XL[, X1 := substr(key, 1, 1)]
XL[, X2 := substr(key, 2, 2)]
XL[, X3 := substr(key, 3, 3)]

# Recode long format (a = +1; b = -1)
XL[, X1c := ifelse(X1 == "a", +1, -1)]
XL[, X2c := ifelse(X2 == "a", +1, -1)]
XL[, X3c := ifelse(X3 == "a", +1, -1)]


### Composite scores to be used with lm
# X2:X3 2-way interaction (for half the data; i.e. when X1 == "a")
X[, X1a_X2.X3 := (aaa - aab) - (aba - abb)]

# X2:X3 2-way interaction (for all the data)
X[, aa := (aaa + baa) / 2]
X[, ab := (aab + bab) / 2]
X[, ba := (aba + bba) / 2]
X[, bb := (abb + bbb) / 2]
X[, X2.X3 := (aa - ab) - (ba - bb)]

# X1:X2:X3 3-way interaction (for all the data)
X[, X1.X2.X3 := ( (aaa - aab) - (aba - abb) ) - ( (baa - bab) - (bba - bbb) )]


### Fit models
# X2:X3 2-way interaction (for half the data; i.e. when X1 == "a")
summary( lm(X1a_X2.X3 ~ 1, X) ) # t = 34.13303
summary( lmer(Y ~ X2c*X3c + (X2c+X3c|id), XL[X1 == "a"]) ) # t = 34.132846  close match
summary( lmer(Y ~ X2c*X3c + (X2c+X3c||id), XL[X1 == "a"]) ) # t = 34.134624  close match

# X2:X3 2-way interaction (for all the data) 
summary( lm(X2.X3 ~ 1, X) ) # t = 0.3075025
summary( lmer(Y ~ X2c*X3c + (X2c+X3c|id), XL) ) # t = 0.1641932
summary( lmer(Y ~ X2c*X3c + (X2c+X3c||id), XL) ) # t = 0.1640710
summary( lmer(Y ~ X2c*X3c + (X2c*X3c|id), XL) ) # t = 0.1641765
anova(   lmer(Y ~ X2c*X3c + (X2c*X3c|id), XL), ddf = "Kenward-Roger" ) # t = 0.1643168
summary( lmer(Y ~ X2c*X3c + (X2c*X3c|id), XL, REML = FALSE) ) # t = 0.1645303
summary( lmer(Y ~ X2c*X3c + (X2c*X3c||id), XL) ) # t = 0.1640704

# X1:X2:X3 3-way interaction (for all the data)
summary( lm(X1.X2.X3 ~ 1, X) ) # t = 46.50177
summary( lmer(Y ~ X1c*X2c*X3c + (X1c*X2c*X3c - X1c:X2c:X3c|id), XL) ) # t = 49.0317599
anova(   lmer(Y ~ X1c*X2c*X3c + (X1c*X2c*X3c - X1c:X2c:X3c|id), XL), ddf = "Kenward-Roger" ) # t = 49.03176
summary( lmer(Y ~ X1c*X2c*X3c + (X1c*X2c*X3c - X1c:X2c:X3c|id), XL, REML = FALSE) ) # t = 49.2677606
summary( lmer(Y ~ X1c*X2c*X3c + (X1c*X2c*X3c - X1c:X2c:X3c||id), XL) ) # t = 46.5193774 close match
summary( lmer(Y ~ X1c*X2c*X3c + (X1c*X2c*X3c|id), XL) ) # unidentifiable
summary( lmer(Y ~ X1c*X2c*X3c + (X1c*X2c*X3c|id), XL,
              control = lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE="ignore")) ) # t = 46.5148684 close match
```

As you can see from above, none of the `lm` estimations are exactly matched by the `lmer` ones. Although some of the results are very similar and may differ only due because of numerical/computational reasons. The gap between both estimation method is specially large for the `X2:X3 2-way interaction (for all the data)`.

My question is if there's a way to obtain the *exact* same results with both methods, and if there is a *correct* way to perform the analyses with `lmer` (although it may not match the `lm` results).

---

Bonus:

I've noticed that the `t value` associated with the 3-way interaction is affected by the way factors are coded, which seems very strange to me:

```r
summary( lmer(Y ~ X1*X2*X3 + (X1*X2*X3 - X1:X2:X3||id), XL) ) # t = 48.36
summary( lmer(Y ~ X1c*X2c*X3c + (X1c*X2c*X3c - X1c:X2c:X3c||id), XL) ) # t = 56.52
```

Comment: +1 because it looks interesting but I have no idea what you are doing here :) Can you explain in words or math why these lm and lmer calls should yield the same coefficients? And what's the logic behind this whole exercise?

Comment: @amoeba I updated my post to clarify the purpose of this post. Basically, I want to reproduce the results from SPSS (which can be translated into an `lm` model) with `lmer`, and also know what is the *correct* `lmer` analyses for this kind of data.

Comment: The reason for the large discrepancy in case of the two-way interaction for the full data is that you have 2 data points per parameter combination. The intuition is that the effective sample size for a mixed model is 2x smaller than for `lm`; I suspect that's why the t-statistic is roughly two times smaller in `lmer`. You would probably be able to observe the same phenomenon using a simpler 2x2 design and looking at the main effects, without bothering with 2x2x2 and complicated interactions.

Answer (score 3):

Strange, when I use your last model, I find a perfect match, not a close match:

```
Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  3.91221    0.07242 99.00001  54.025   <2e-16 ***
X1c          0.03277    0.05006 99.00000   0.655    0.514    
X2c         -0.04836    0.04644 99.00000  -1.042    0.300    
X3c          0.04248    0.05009 99.00001   0.848    0.398    
X1c:X2c      0.08370    0.08747 98.99998   0.957    0.341    
X1c:X3c     -0.07025    0.08895 98.99994  -0.790    0.432    
X2c:X3c     -0.02957    0.09616 99.00000  -0.308    0.759    
X1c:X2c:X3c -8.14099    0.17507 99.00003 -46.502   <2e-16 ***
```

Comment: Just to be clear, which model are you referring to?

Comment: summary( lmer(Y ~ X1c*X2c*X3c + (X1c*X2c*X3c|id), XL,
              control = lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE="ignore")) )

Comment: This is indeed very strange! `summary( lmer(Y ~ X1c*X2c*X3c + (X1c*X2c*X3c|id), XL, control=lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE="ignore")) )$coefficients` returns `t = 46.5148684` for me. Might be a version issue? I'm using `R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)` and `lmerTest 3.1-0`.

Comment: I have the same R & lmerTest versions as @mat and get the same results as them (albeit with many warnings - failure to converge, etc).

Comment: @mkt this is so strange! I even tried from a different PC and I still get these results. How can this be possible? Which version of `lme4` do you have? I've `lme4 1.1-21`

Comment: @mat Perhaps I wasn't clear - I'm getting the same results as you! I think you're probably right that user244839 is using a different version than we are.